# Add method inside RequestMapping SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot

I am adding two-factor authentication in my Java Web Project. In the login page, user has to type in username, password and security code (Secure code will start generating in login page). If these three match, they can access the main page.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "")
    public String login() throws InterruptedException, GeneralSecurityException {
        getSecureCode();
        return "login";   // return to login.jsp
    }

 public void getSecureCode() throws InterruptedException, GeneralSecurityException {

    String base32Secret = TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.generateBase32Secret(16);
    String keyId = "abc123";
    logger.info("Image url = " + TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.qrImageUrl(keyId, base32Secret));
    code = TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.generateCurrentNumberString(base32Secret);
    while (true) {

        long diff = TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.DEFAULT_TIME_STEP_SECONDS
                - ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.DEFAULT_TIME_STEP_SECONDS);
        code = TimeBasedOneTimePasswordUtil.generateCurrentNumberString(base32Secret);
        logger.info("Secret code = " + code + ", change in " + diff + " seconds");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

 // after button in login.jsp clicked
 @RequestMapping(value = "check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

I added a `getSecureCode` method, so the user can get the security code inside the login page. Unfortunately, the web page not getting loaded. If I remove only it works.

P/S : For the two factor authentication, I refer https://github.com/j256/two-factor-auth

Comment: Your thinking here is fundamentally flawed.You need to amend your question to detail what you would like to achieve rather than asking why you existing code does not work because it will simply never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop will never exit, so the thread that is supposed to process the request and return the response will get stuck indefinitely.

Comment: You haven't exactly stated what you're trying to accomplish with the while loop. If it's for the code to change every X seconds, that's much more complicated than this.

Comment: I can't put the method inside the POST method as the code should start generating before the button in jsp clicked.

Comment: That's correct. The easiest way is perhaps to do periodic AJAX requests from the login page. When handling the AJAX request, check whether a new code is needed and if so, send it to the client.